# Wordpress - проблема реализации

Tags: wordpress, cms, движок, реализация

Есть сайт про транспорт. Есть 2 разных типа записей для авто и для байков. У каждого типа записи реализована марка через категории(рубрики,метки и тд).
Пример авто) запись Accord -> марка Honda
       байк) запись CB Shine ->  марка Honda
Первая категория Honda со второй никак не связана.
Теперь вопрос - как сделать марку как связующее звено для авто и для байков.
Что бы Honda стал общим для авто и байков?

Comment: Если Honda это терм таксономии "Марка", в чем проблема разрешить таксономию "Марка" для пост типа "Авто" и пост типа "Байк" ? 
Как додавались пост типы(через код или плагин)?

Comment: И в правду, спасибо. До этого не замечал что можно одну и ту же категорию на разные типы записи вешать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function create_taxonomy(){
register_taxonomy('taxonomy', array('auto' , 'bike'), array());
}
```